# How to check if a boolean is set to true and then push it to the nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

At this moment the comments will be pushed inside the array, but then I click on a placed comment, and put some text in the input field and click on add...it should be pushed into the nested array. Looking at the comments, it should check if enableReply is set on true, if that is the case then new added comment should be pushed into this index in a nested array. So my question is, how should I do that. Another possible option is to first check if enableReplyComment is set on true before it go deeper to the comments array and check the **image.comments.enableReply** if this was being set on true.

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu/instagram-redux)

[image]

```js
        case types.ADD_COMMENT: {
            console.log(state);
            return {
                ...state,
                imageData: state.imageData.map(text => text.id === action.id ?
                    {   
                        ...text, 
                        comments: [...text.comments, {comment: action.newComment, likeComment: text.toggle, enableReply: false, replyComments: [{}]}]
                    } : text
                ) 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do... Can you show what the `imageData` is supposed to look like given different inputs?

Comment: i just added a link to codesandbox...this give you a better understanding of what I mean.

Comment: In your screenshot there's a comment that has `enableReply` set to `true` and one that's set to `false`. Can you further explain what you mean by `Looking at the comments, it should check if enableReply is set on true, if that is the case then new added comment should be pushed into this index in a nested array.` Does this mean if at least **one** comment has `enableReply` set to `false` it should not add a new `comment` into the `comments` array?

Comment: I want to build the same thing as instagram/facebook. The enableReply will only set to true if someone clicks on reply of course.

Comment: where's the `nested array` you're talking about? I am looking at your `CodeSandbox` example but clicking on `Click here to reply" just toggles between this message and `x`.

Comment: That is exact the problem lol. Therefore I drop the question on Stack Overflow ....